# Pandas : How to handle overlapping times for a specific column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to work on a dataframe to handle overlapping timeranges and I am finding it difficult to proceed. I have a dataframe with the values that I have shown below. I have around 400,000 lines in my dataframe. Can anyone please help on what function I can use to get the results (for the 3 uses cases)?

Many thanks for your help, in advance.

*I have 4 use cases :*

**1. Case 1:
Alarm 1 has no EndTime but since Alarm1,2 and 3 have overlapping times, I need the lowest starttime of the Three and the end of the largest (here, in this cas, its without an  end)**

```
   |------ALARM1--------- (no end)
    |----ALARM2-----|
|-------ALARM3--|      

<--------------------------...


    

   ELEMENT                                      TEXT                                       ID         START                       END

   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25                         ALARM1                                    5        2021-01-19 05:00:00                 NaT
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25                         ALARM2                                 772874243   2021-01-20 06:00:00     2021-01-20 08:00:00
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25                         ALARM3                                 772874243   2021-01-20 04:00:19     2021-01-20 10:03:16
   
   Result 
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25                         ALARM3                                    5        2021-01-19 04:00:00                 NaT
```

**2. Case 2: Alarm2 is contained completely in Alarm1**

```
|-----ALARM1----|
   |---ALARM2-| 

<--------------->   

   ELEMENT                                      TEXT                                       ID         START                       END

   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT26                         ALARM1                                    5        2021-01-19 05:00:00     2021-01-20 10:00:00
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT26                         ALARM2                                 772874243   2021-01-20 06:00:00     2021-01-20 08:00:00

   
   Result 
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT26                         ALARM1                                    5        2021-01-19 05:00:00     2021-01-20 10:00:00
```

**3. Case 3: Alarm2 and Alarm1 have a common overlapping time**

```
|-----ALARM1----|
           |---ALARM2-| 
<--------------------->

   ELEMENT                                      TEXT                                       ID         START                       END

   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT27                         ALARM1                                    5        2021-01-17 05:00:00     2021-01-19 10:00:00
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT27                         ALARM2                                 772874243   2021-01-18 06:00:00     2021-01-20 08:00:00

   
   Result 
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT27                         ALARM1                                    5        2021-01-17 05:00:00     2021-01-20 08:00:00
```

**Case 4: Alarm2 starts exactly at the end of Alarm1**

Here I need to get only one line, that contains the start of Alarm1 and the end of Alarm2

I have tried to use the following code but it does not help and I dont know how to address this issue.

```
df['newid']=(df['START']-df['END'].shift()).dt.total_seconds().gt(0).cumsum()

print(df.to_string(index=False))
grouped = df.groupby(df['ELEMENT'])
print(grouped.get_group('OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT29').to_string(index=False))
print(grouped.get_group('OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25').to_string(index=False))
```

I am quite a novice and need help.

```
                ELEMENT                                     TEXT         ID               START                 END  newid
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT29                            ACCES_DEGRADE          5 2021-01-19 18:07:22                 NaT  10975
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT29                            ACCES_DEGRADE          5 2021-01-19 19:07:42                 NaT  10975
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT29                            ACCES_DEGRADE          5 2021-01-19 19:52:57                 NaT  10975
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT29  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-19 19:52:57 2021-01-19 21:38:23  10975
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT29                            ACCES_DEGRADE          5 2021-01-19 23:09:02                 NaT  10976
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT29  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-19 23:09:02 2021-01-19 23:23:58  10976
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT29  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-20 08:50:54 2021-01-20 09:05:51  10977
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT29  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-20 10:06:18 2021-01-20 10:36:21  10978
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT29  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-20 11:17:29 2021-01-20 12:02:37  10979
                ELEMENT                                     TEXT         ID               START                 END  newid
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-19 20:59:06 2021-01-19 21:29:08  10971
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25                            ACCES_DEGRADE          5 2021-01-19 23:24:53 2021-01-22 03:14:53  10972
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-20 06:47:20 2021-01-20 07:02:17  10972
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-20 09:48:19 2021-01-20 10:03:16  10973
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-20 10:18:29 2021-01-20 11:18:41  10974
 OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-20 11:33:55 2021-01-20 11:48:52  10975
```

When I have the following input:

```
                ELEMENT                                     TEXT         ID               START                 END
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT27  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-19 22:00:00 2021-01-19 22:30:00
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT27  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-19 22:30:00 2021-01-19 23:44:12
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT27  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-19 23:30:00 2021-01-19 23:46:12
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT30  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-19 19:30:00                 NaT
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT30  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-19 20:00:00 2021-01-19 23:00:00
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT31  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-19 18:00:00 2021-01-19 19:00:00
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT31  The signal degrade of ONTi (SDi) occurs  772874243 2021-01-19 20:30:00 2021-01-19 23:00:00
```

For the ELEMENT OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT31, it must print 2 lines instead of one as there is no overlapping.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I was not precise. I will add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there might be simpler and optimal solution than following. You can use [`group_by`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) however if you have huge data then following might perform slow.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

# Data preprocessing(ignore)
data = StringIO('''
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25,                         ALARM1,                                    5,        2021-01-19 05:00:00,     NaT       
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25,                         ALARM2,                                 772874243,   2021-01-20 06:00:00,     2021-01-20 08:00:00
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25,                         ALARM3,                                 772874243,   2021-01-20 04:00:19,     2021-01-20 10:03:16
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT26,                         ALARM1,                                    5,        2021-01-19 05:00:00,     2021-01-20 10:00:00
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT26,                         ALARM2,                                 772874243,   2021-01-20 06:00:00,     2021-01-20 08:00:00
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT27,                         ALARM1,                                    5,        2021-01-17 05:00:00,     2021-01-19 10:00:00
   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT27,                         ALARM2,                                 772874243,   2021-01-18 06:00:00,     2021-01-20 08:00:00
''')

df = pd.read_csv(data,names=['ELEMENT','TEXT','ID','START','END'])
df['START'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START'])
df['END'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END'],errors ='coerce')


#See from below
gb = df.groupby(by ='ELEMENT')

def group_filter(group):
  
  min = group['START'].min()
  max = group['END'].max()
  id = group.loc[ group['START'] == min]['ID'].iloc[0]
  text = group.loc[group['START'] == min]['TEXT'].iloc[0]
  result = None

  #Put your conditions here....
  if np.isnat(group['END']).any():
    max = pd.to_datetime('NAT',errors='coerce')
    result = pd.Series([id,text,min,max])
  
  result = pd.Series([id,text,min,max])
  return result
  
output = gb.apply(group_filter).reset_index()
output.columns = df.columns
output
```

Output:

```
ELEMENT TEXT    ID  START   END
0   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT25  5   ALARM1  2021-01-19 05:00:00 NaT
1   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT26  5   ALARM1  2021-01-19 05:00:00 2021-01-20 10:00:00
2   OLT5134-LT4-PON0-ONT27  5   ALARM1  2021-01-17 05:00:00 2021-01-20 08:00:00
```

Comment: Hi it works for all use cases :)  but one :( , when there is no overlapping of time ranges, it must print all lines that dont overlap for the ELEMENTS., I have edit the example: OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT31) , any hints?

Comment: umm for that I guess you have to modify the solution little bit as the condition you are telling involves multiple rows in single iteration. Current solution creates a single row record in one iteration. You can write another `apply` function just to filter out and create your desired output and then merge with my solution.